# Muliple CustomViews to add in single Layout :: Android

Tags: android

I have many custom Views. I want to show a specific custom view on Layout. I am using a View and trying to initialize it with custom view. its not working any help please?

```
View custom=(View)findViewById(R.id.animation_View);
    custom=new CustomeView(this, null);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);
```

Activity_XMl

```
 <View
    android:id="@+id/animation_View"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

</View>
```

Comment: post the activity_animation.xml..

Comment: I have edited Question please review now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately. your approach is wrong. You are inflating a view from xml and then again assigning a new programmatically created `CustomView`. If your custom view is `CustomView`, then there is no need to programmatically create a new `CustomView`.

Your final code should be,

```
View custom=(View)findViewById(R.id.animation_View);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);
```

assuming you have correctly extended a `View` class and added it to your `activity_animation` xml. For help regarding creating custom view components, check out-

1. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html
2. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-custom-views-2/
3. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using a `CustomView`

First way is using XML file:-

For example, change the `activity_animation.xml` file as

```
<com.myapp.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/animation_View"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

</com.myapp.CustomView>
```

Note that the `com.myapp` should be replaced with the package name in which you have `CustomView`.

Then set this xml in ur activity as

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);
```

Second way, is doing it dynamically, without using any xml:-

```
CustomView customView = new CustomeView(this, null);
setContentView(customView);
```

Comment: Let me try second one because its close to my requirment